# APN priority from Parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

I am using Parse.com as a backend and to send push notifications. I understand that in the notification payload it is possible to set the "priority" as per the apple documentation:

```
Priority
1 byte
The notification’s priority. Provide one of the following values:
10 The push message is sent immediately.
The remote notification must trigger an alert, sound, or badge on the device. It is an error to use this priority for a push that contains only the content-available key.
5 The push message is sent at a time that conserves power on the device receiving it.
```

Obviously having the message delivered immediately is more desirable (I'm building a messaging app) Does it make a difference if I set the priority to "10" on Parse? Or does Parse set its own priority? Any pointers on this would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Kex, did you ever get an answer for this?

Comment: @JoshGafni, not yet buddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up sending a nil sound file in the package  which seeks to up the priority. It would be nice to manually set the priority though.

Comment: Why does that up the priority? You mean you have to have some sound set or set to nil right? I actually have a .wav set in the payload.

Comment: Yeah or silence.wav. There are a few posts from parse saying that apple wants you to only send pushes without sounds or alerts at low priority, so that's how they've implemented it. Sending a nil sound should up the priority but it's not clear by how much.

Comment: cool cheers for that. Got a bit of discussion here about silent notifications too that you might find interesting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761049/push-notifications-that-trigger-a-background-refresh-before-showing-the-push-not